# Validate the switch statement with an if statement

Tags: java

- Use a switch statement to implement a menu. Allow the user to enter correct upper/lowercase letters (i.e. AIR or air or Air or aiR etc ). If the user enters an invalid selection your program should tell them and then exit.
- The answers for air, water and steel must use printf. Display air to 3 decimal places, water to 4 decimal places and steel to 5 decimal places.
- After the user enters the distance the sound wave must travel but before using the number in a calculation, validate it. If the distance is less than zero or greater than 10000, display an error message and do no further processing ie exit. Nest the switch statement (menu – see above) within this if statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

   public class SpeedSound
   {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        String input;       
        double distance;
        double time;
        final double AIR   = 1/1100;
        final double WATER = 1/4900;
        final double STEEL = 1/16400;

        Scanner kyb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the corresponding medium:\n ");
        System.out.println("Air\n ");
        System.out.println("Water\n ");
        System.out.println("Steel\n ");
        input = kyb.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter the distance: ");   
        distance = kyb.nextDouble();

       if (distance < 0 || distance > 10000)
             System.out.print("Error: ");

           switch (input)
            {
                case "Air":
                case "AIR":
                time = (distance / 1100);
           System.out.println("The total time traveled is " + time + "seconds.");
        break;

        case "Water":
        case "WATER":   
        time = (distance / 4900);
        System.out.println("The total time traveled is " + time + "seconds.");
        break;

        case "Steel":
        case "STEEL":
        time = (distance / 16400);
        System.out.println("The total time traveled is " + time + "seconds.");
        break;

        }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Allow the user to enter correct upper/lowercase letters (i.e. AIR or air or Air or aiR etc )

As you need to handle all the `lower/upper` case version of the input. Just convert the string into `lower case`before passing to `switch case`, then define there only lowercase `case` statements instead of multiple statements.

```
intput = input.toLowerCase();   // this is not require if you have converted it earlier
switch (input) {
case "air":
```

> If the user enters an invalid selection your program should tell them and then exit.

You can use the `if condition` and exit the user:

```
input = kyb.nextLine().toLowerCase();

if (! (input.equals("air") || input.equals("water") || input.equals("steel")) ) {
  System.out.println("Invalid input. Exit");
  return;
}
```

> If the distance is less than zero or greater than 10000, display an error message and do no further processing ie exit.

```
   if (distance < 0 || distance > 10000) {
         System.out.print("Error: ");
         return;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, i understand what you mean but the if statement should be validating the distance i entered if my distance is <0 or >10000 it should display an error message any number inside 0 to 10000 should calculate depending on the input i pick. the switch statement supposed to have the input (air, water, and steel) calculation. my code compiles but when i try to enter the distance it stops compiling.

Comment: Also I'm only allowed to use one if statement and a switch statement nested inside it. Thank you in advance

Comment: `If the user enters an invalid selection your program should tell them and then exit.` you will need one if for this and another for `distance` input.

Comment: just wondering if i could do this:                                                                      input = kyb.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase();

Comment: No. This is a comparison. As you are using switch case so use cannot use it, otherwise this can be used in if condition.

Comment: yeah my bad i realized it after i sent the msg. just one last question if i already have System.out.println("The total time traveled is " + time + "seconds."); how am i going to display the time in printf? The answers for air, water and steel must use printf. Display air to 3 decimal places, water to 4 decimal places and steel to 5 decimal places. i edited my code trying to use printf but its not working.

Comment: check it [Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html). You will find all the information with example

Answer (score 0):

Indentation doesn't matter for java, use a block by using {} braces, otherwise it will only execute the next statement.

```
if (condition) {
// .. lots of 
// .. lines of
// .. code


}
```

Comment: i also tried that before but it is not working that way it suppose to.